# Nested Enums in Swift 4

Tags: swift, enums

The current implementation of extracting data from long nested enums appears to be quite tedious and the upkeep of such structures laborious. Below is an example of an implementation I have and just wanted some input whether this is truly the correct way to extract data from these enums

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

enum HousingType {
    case House(HousingSubType)
    case Apartment(HousingSubType)
    case Mansion(HousingSubType)

    enum HousingSubType: CaseIterable {
        case Victorian
        case Modern
        case Standard
    }

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case let .House(subtype):
            switch subtype {
            case .Modern:
                return Structure.House.Modern.name
            case .Standard:
                return Structure.House.Standard.name
            case .Victorian:
                return Structure.House.Victorian.name
            }
        case let .Apartment(subtype):
            switch subtype {
            case .Modern:
                return Structure.Apartment.Modern.name
            case .Standard:
                return Structure.Apartment.Standard.name
            case .Victorian:
                return Structure.Apartment.Victorian.name
            }
        case let .Mansion(subtype):
            switch subtype {
            case .Modern:
                return Structure.Mansion.Modern.name
            case .Standard:
                return Structure.Mansion.Standard.name
            case .Victorian:
                return Structure.Mansion.Victorian.name
            }
        }
    }

    static var allCases: [HousingType] {
        return
            HousingType.HousingSubType.allCases.map(HousingType.House)
                + HousingType.HousingSubType.allCases.map(HousingType.Apartment)
                + HousingType.HousingSubType.allCases.map(HousingType.Mansion)
    }
}

enum Structure {
    enum House {
        enum Victorian {
            static let name = "Victorian House"
            static let rooms = 4
            static let bathrooms = 1
        }
        enum Modern {
            static let name = "Modern House"
            static let rooms = 4
            static let bathrooms = 4
        }
        enum Standard {
            static let name = "Standard House"
            static let rooms = 4
            static let bathrooms = 2
        }
    }

    enum Apartment {
        enum Victorian {
            static let name = "Victorian Apartment"
            static let rooms = 2
            static let bathrooms = 1
        }
        enum Modern {
            static let name = "Modern Apartment"
            static let rooms = 2
            static let bathrooms = 2
        }
        enum Standard {
            static let name = "Standard Apartment"
            static let rooms = 2
            static let bathrooms = 1
        }
    }

    enum Mansion {
        enum Victorian {
            static let name = "Victorian Mansion"
            static let rooms = 10
            static let bathrooms = 3
        }
        enum Modern {
            static let name = "Modern Mansion"
            static let rooms = 10
            static let bathrooms = 10
        }
        enum Standard {
            static let name = "Standard Mansion"
            static let rooms = 10
            static let bathrooms = 6
        }
    }
}
```

Output for:

```
for type in HousingType.allCases {
    print(type.name)
}
```

Is:

```
Victorian House
Modern House
Standard House
Victorian Apartment
Modern Apartment
Standard Apartment
Victorian Mansion
Modern Mansion
Standard Mansion
```

And output for

```
let apartment = HousingType.Apartment(.Modern)
print(apartment.name)
```

is:

```
Modern Apartment
```

I can easily obtain data from enums and iterate through all the cases, but as you can see, it's a ton of code to go through each possible case for a single variable `name`. As I add code to get `rooms` or `bathrooms` or as additional `HousingSubType` are added, the length of this implementation gets extremely long.

Is there a better way to obtain variable `name` without having to explicitly write out each possible case through a series of switch statements? Is there a different implementation entirely I should look into when attempting to have a series of static variables of various types, subtypes, subsubtypes, etc?

Comment: Maybe you should use a class to subclass these instead of enums??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be missing something you really want to do, but I usually do not use nested types to represent a data structure which needs to be parsed and accessed dynamically.

Seeing your example code, I would use Dictionary.

```
enum HousingType: Hashable {
    case house(HousingSubType)
    case apartment(HousingSubType)
    case mansion(HousingSubType)

    enum HousingSubType: CaseIterable {
        case victorian
        case modern
        case standard
    }

    var name: String {
        return structures[self]!.name
    }

    static var allCases: [HousingType] {
        return
            HousingType.HousingSubType.allCases.map(HousingType.house)
                + HousingType.HousingSubType.allCases.map(HousingType.apartment)
                + HousingType.HousingSubType.allCases.map(HousingType.mansion)
    }
}

struct Structure {
    let name: String
    let rooms: Int
    let bathrooms: Int
}

let structures: [HousingType: Structure] = [
    .house(.victorian): Structure(
        name: "Victorian House",
        rooms: 4,
        bathrooms: 1
    ),
    .house(.modern): Structure(
        name: "Modern House",
        rooms: 4,
        bathrooms: 4
    ),
    .house(.standard): Structure(
        name: "Standard House",
        rooms: 4,
        bathrooms: 2
    ),
    .apartment(.victorian): Structure(
        name: "Victorian Apartment",
        rooms: 2,
        bathrooms: 1
    ),
    .apartment(.modern): Structure(
        name: "Modern Apartment",
        rooms: 2,
        bathrooms: 2
    ),
    .apartment(.standard): Structure(
        name: "Standard Apartment",
        rooms: 2,
        bathrooms: 1
    ),
    .mansion(.victorian): Structure(
        name: "Victorian Mansion",
        rooms: 10,
        bathrooms: 3
    ),
    .mansion(.modern): Structure(
        name: "Modern Mansion",
        rooms: 10,
        bathrooms: 10
    ),
    .mansion(.standard): Structure(
        name: "Standard Mansion",
        rooms: 10,
        bathrooms: 6
    ),
]
```

Comment: This is great, didn't think to use the enum as a key! Such a simpler method. Thank you! If I may ask then, how would you approach creating a static data structure if enums or this method isn't how you would do it?

Comment: @BlueGuy, frankly I cannot imagine what you have in mind. But the answer might depend on the details. I would think how I would do when I find more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

While it's difficult to recommend an approach without understanding all the information you want to model and the requirements for using it, it is possible slightly modify the approach you are using in your sample enums to require less code.

For example, this implementation seems to accomplish the same initial results you were looking for (it prints the same results for `HousingType.allCases` and allows for the identical creation and printing the name of a single instance).  However, it uses a slightly different approach to significantly reduce the lines of code needed:

```
enum HousingType: CaseIterable {
    case House(HousingSubType)
    case Apartment(HousingSubType)
    case Mansion(HousingSubType)

    enum HousingSubType: String, CaseIterable {
        case Victorian
        case Modern
        case Standard
    }

    static var allCases: [HousingType] {
        return Array(HousingSubType.allCases.map{ [HousingType.House($0), HousingType.Apartment($0), HousingType.Mansion($0) ] }.joined())
    }

    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .House(let subtype): return subtype.rawValue + " House"
            case .Apartment(let subtype): return subtype.rawValue + " Apartment"
            case .Mansion(let subtype): return subtype.rawValue + " Mansion"
        }
    }
}
```